# Psychology literature on present bias

Tags: cognitive

Does anyone know some good psychology papers on present bias that discusses the psychological mechanisms underlying this bias?

I can only seem to find papers by economist and they tend to give a quite formal and mathematical explanation of the subject. I'm looking for an in depth explanation of the psychology behind present bias.

Comment: Indeed economists use the present bias, as well as reasearchers on gaming. In psychological research I would recommend you search for SALIENCE.

Answer (score 1):

I think the present bias is a result of the immediate gratification tendency that we as humans have. The following extracts are from the book [Smart Change: Break the habits that hold you back and form the habits of success by Art Markman](https://books.google.com.cy/books?id=-p5ZognR-ZwC&dq=Smart%20Change:%20Break%20the%20habits%20that%20hold%20you%20back%20and%20form%20the%20habits%20of%20success%20by%20Art%20Markman&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6pLi88ozUAhVIalAKHRPLA5sQ6AEIHzAA)

> One of the most difficult things for people (and other animals for
>   that matter) is to pass up something desirable right now in favor of
>   something else in the future. A piece of cake now has a stronger pull
>   on our actions than having a beach-ready body by next summer. An
>   afternoon playing video games feels like a better way to spend an
>   afternoon than studying for an exam that won’t happen for another
>   week. Checking a few emails at work feels more productive than putting
>   in effort on a big long-term project that won’t be finished for
>   months. You’re wired to want to do what feels good in the short term.
>
> [A beautiful experimental method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_marshmallow_experiment) for looking at the difficulty of
>   overcoming temptations was developed by Walter Mischel in the late
>   1950s to study how children deal with temptation. In his studies, an
>   experimenter asked four-year-old children to sit in a room and showed
>   them a small tempting object like a marshmallow or a cookie. Then the
>   experimenter placed the object in front of the child next to a bell
>   and said that he had to leave the room for a while. If the child was
>   able to wait until the experimenter got back, then the child would get
>   a larger reward (like two marshmallows or cookies). However, the child
>   could ring the bell at any time and just take what was on the plate.
>   If the child was able to wait fifteen minutes, then the experimenter
>   would come back in the room and give the child the bigger reward.
>
> In a typical experiment, the average child was able to go only about
>   ten minutes before ringing the bell. Factored into that average are
>   the many children who rang the bell soon after the experimenter left
>   the room and others who were able to wait the full fifteen minutes.
>   Even for those children who are successful at waiting, it can be a
>   difficult experience. In fact, there are a number of popular videos on
>   YouTube of children in these experiments agonizing over the
>   marshmallows in front of them. It is funny to see the children
>   struggle to wait for the bigger reward. But the videos also illustrate
>   how hard it can be to overcome temptation.

In the above experiment although the future benefits are clearly better (two instead of one marshmallow), the now is weighted more.